# Touch Screen not working

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, touchscreen

I am using Samsung Galaxy Pro B7510. The problem is that my touch screen is not working sometimes. It has been like this for several weeks. I use Pin lock feature to unlock the phone and EZanswer Trial to attend calls. This is possible only because of the qwerty keyboard. Without which I would be doomed. Some times the touch screen starts working for some time and then, without a warning, it becomes not responding. No error messages are seen.

This all started when after I upgraded it into GingerBread 2.3.6 and rooting . After seeing this problem, I downgraded into the stock rom, unrooted it, and everything.

Not sure if its a software issue or hardware problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this issue before when I rooted my galaxy ace it was extremely random and I fixed it by flashing an old stock rom and then using Kies to upgrade to the latest.

If this doesn't work it would suggest that your digitizer has gone, or is in the process of going. If you have time remaining on your warranty, and have returned it to stock, you should be able to return it for repair to samsung.

Comment: I tried to update firmware after flashing stock rom, because I heard it may cure it, but kies always says that my phone doesn't support flash upgrade.

Comment: It is out of warrenty :-(
maybe digitizer is going to be gone, don't know.
Is there anyway I can check my digitizer?

Comment: If kies wont allow you to upgrade you are still using some form custom firmware. http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/ try getting a stock firmware from there.

Comment: Downloaded and Flashed...
But kies was always like that. Even the first time I connected(Stock ROM)

Comment: There is no way to check that I know of other than attempting to use your touchscreen and the issue you have with kies is very strange and something i have never heard of.

Comment: It might be because this phone is not as famous/marketed/sold like ace or S series..

Comment: One another thing, 
The touch screen works for a few seconds when I press it too strongly...
I know it is dangerous for the phone and it might break, but Frustrated......

Comment: For future reference for anyone who comes to see this post,
CHANGE THE CHARGER!!!!!

Even if you are using the original one, My touch screen is working now...