# Touch screen on tablet suddenly not working

Tags: tablet, touchscreen

[This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75230/touch-screen-not-working) seemingly related question isn't relevant, as it concerns a replaced screen, and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57766/touch-screen-not-working) question involves an intermittent problem.

My tablet suddenly stopped responding to touch. I haven't dropped it or otherwise damaged it. It does respond to a USB keyboard, although it is extremely inconvenient to do so.  I factory rest it, but he problem persists.

It's a no-name, and not worth having it repaired. Can anyone think of any software options which might get it working again?

Comment: Is the touch screen completely dead or are some regions still work. You can use a touch screen test app. If some parts still work cleaning the screen may help you (see manual how to do so).

Comment: It is completely dead

Comment: Related: [My Google Pixel 2's touch screen suddenly quit working--how can I fix it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232564/my-google-pixel-2s-touch-screen-suddenly-quit-working-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try force restarting it at least for 2-3 time... if it still doesn't respond, then use a clear bag by filling it with raw rice and leave your tab in it for a few days.

Comment: I know of the rice tip when a 'phone is dropped in water, but this was not. And it works perfectly when controlled by keyboard.

Comment: Then there could be a fault in any of the boards present in it.